# Include a component as FormControl Angular2

Tags: angular, components, angular2-forms

I have component that has form built through form builder and now in that form i need to include a component that has only one input box as a form control.

add.ts

```
this.newForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required]],
      surname:['', [Validators.required]],
      time: ''
    });
```

"time" has to be included as a different component.

add.html

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="name">{{'forms.newForm.label.configuration.name' | translate}}</label>  
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <input type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="placeholder" 
                  class="form-control input-md" type="text">
              <small *ngIf="!newForm.controls.name.valid && newForm.controls.name.dirty" class="text-danger">
                Name is required.
              </small>
            </div>

            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="surname">{{'forms.newForm.label.configuration.name' | translate}}</label>  
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <input type="text" formControlName="surname" placeholder="placeholder" 
                  class="form-control input-md" type="text">
              <small *ngIf="!newForm.controls.surname.valid && newForm.controls.name.dirty" class="text-danger">
                Surname is required.
              </small>
            </div>
          </div>
```

time.html

```
<div>
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <input class="form-control input-md" type="text" (keydown)="eventHandler($event)" maxlength="11">
    <small *ngIf="!validTime" class="text-danger">
      Invalid time
    </small>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to i include form control "time" as a component in the main form so i can access the value through this.newForm.controls['time'].value??

Comment: is this parent and child?

Comment: @AJT_82 yes.. it is parent and child

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A single `FormControl` cannot be passed separately to the child component in that way, you need to bind it with `[formControl]` to be able to do that, create a custom form control or pass it within a formgroup to the child. Here it will be easiest to bind the control with `[formControl]` in the child:

```ts
this.newForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', [Validators.required]],
    surname:['', [Validators.required]],
    time: ['']
});
```

In your parent html pass the `time` formcontrol to your child:

```html
<time-comp [time]="newForm.get('time')"></time-comp>
```

and child template:

```html
<input [formControl]="time">
```

And do not forget to mark the form control received from parent with `Input`:

```ts
@Input() time: FormControl;
```

Then you can access the `time` value (in your parent) with:

```ts
this.newForm.get('time').value;
```

Also notice that you do not need any events, like `keyup`, the changes will be catched by the parent without them.

Answer (score 0):

As of Angular 8, it is possible to pass FormControl as a @Input to a child component without having to put it inside a formGroup and it would still work with two-way binding. An example.. https://angular-v2yaaw.stackblitz.io

Comment: Please provide source code link instead of output link.