# Angular2 - Submit Dynamically created Child form by Parent Form Button Click

Tags: angular

**Scenario:**
I am creating a child form with controls dynamically, after receiving child form control information from a service in the parent component.

I am following the below link:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html

Now how to Submit that Dynamically created Child Form by clicking on a button in a Parent Form component and can access child form values in Parent Form Component?

**Considering the following options:**
I am not sure whether the following approach

https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2

Also I am thinking if raising events from child components with data that parent component will listen to get the child form values in Parent component.

Please advice...

Comment: ...please post code, what have you tried? :)

Comment: Let me check if i can create a plunkr

Comment: Great, even better! :)

Comment: @AJT_82 I hope the question is clear enough to share your thoughts in the mean time

Comment: Yeah, I think you are on the right track. The second link is very good to add controls dynamically, and then this answer could help you if you from my understanding have childcomponent that has some parts of the form? The good thing is, that you do not need any special event handlers here, the changes made in the form in the child is catched by the parent :) There is a sample plunker as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42340480/6294072